# How can I Bind by convention a generic interface to a multiple generic concrete type in Ninject

Tags: c#, generics, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have a multiple object that implements the same generic interface. So, I want to configure it using Ninject conventions but I don't know how to do it.

Right now I have these registrations

```
Bind<IQueryHandler<GetPagedPostsQuery, PagedResult<Post>>>().To<GetPagedPostsQueryHandler>();
Bind<IQueryHandler<GetPostByDateQuery, Post>>().To<GetPostByDateQueryHandler>();
```

I tried this convention

```
Kernel.Bind(x => x
  .FromThisAssembly()
  .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
  .SelectAllClasses()
  .InheritedFrom(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
  .BindDefaultInterface());
```

But doesn't register any query handler.

Is posible to do it with conventions?

** Edit **
The classes are the followings

```
public class GetPagedPostsQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetPagedPostsQuery, PagedResult<Post>>
public class GetPostByDateQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<GetPostByDateQuery, Post>
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation (.. well not entirely just what types it inherits) of `GetPagedPostsQuery` and `GetPostByDateQueryHandler`?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I addd the info, but the Frank answer works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BindDefaultInterface` means that `MyService : IMyService, IWhatever` will be bound to `IMyService`.

You should use `BindSingleInterface`, which worked instantly when I tried it in a Unit Test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    kernel.Bind(c => c.FromThisAssembly()
                        .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
                        .SelectAllClasses()
                        .InheritedFrom(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
                        .BindSingleInterface());

    kernel.TryGet<IQueryHandler<GetPagedPostsQuery,PagedResult<Post>>>()
        .Should()
        .NotBeNull();
}
```

Comment: i agree that `BindSingleInterface` should work, but i think that `BindDefaultInterface` should have worked as well - after all @vfabre is sticking to the naming convention (`IQueryHandler` -> `XYZQueryHandler`).

Comment: Great! this works for me, also great idea to create a unit test to check it.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I already test the BindDefaultInterface but ninject cannot resolve it. I don't understand exactly why. But thanks to both